# how to handle mysql tables with same id

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new to programming. In my project I have two `mysql` tables with the field names as following:

1. `student(id,name,mail,password)`
2. `article(art_name,description)`

The logic is: after login `student` can write an `article`.
In `article` table `description` field may be very big texts.
My question is

1. What will be the data_type of the field(description) which may
   contain minimum 4000 characters
2. How can I maintain the two tables that a student posts an article?

Comment: You could use nvarchar(max) for your field type as this would allow for much more than 4000 characters to be stored. What do you mean by maintain the two tables that a student posts an article. Can you run me through what you want to have happen?

Comment: 2nd question is, suppose i want to fetch an article by its student name..how can I fetch??that means How can I store the value of an article table that I can fetch who posted it.

Comment: You would need to store the ID of the student posting this in the article table. So student would be `student(id,name,mail,password)` and article would be `article(id,art_name,description)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nvarchar(max) for your field type as this would allow for much more than 4000 characters to be stored. So would be perfect for storing the article.

As for the database and being able to fetch an article written by a particular student, you would need to store the ID of the student posting it against the article table.

E.g

```
Student(id,name,mail,password)
Article(id,art_name,description)
```

Comment: With a query to the database and a join between the databases. Do you have any code written that you can post?

Comment: I understand that I have to join in the database query..My question is :after login,a window will display,this window contains "article name,descrption"..when I submit that how it will fetch the student id which will store into the databse

Comment: Do you need it to be the student ID of the person logged in? As you could just store that in a session variable (or something similar depending on the code with which your application is built), and then call that when making the query.